# how to convert string to date pandas python TypeError: strptime() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, string, date, pandas

I have a dataframe with some text dates in them. I would like to return the dates: year, month and day in separate columns. But in order to do that I need to first convert the text(from excel) to a date.

The code I have now is

```
def convertdate(dstring):
    dt = time.strptime(dstring, date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
    return dt
```

However it returns an: `TypeError: strptime() takes no keyword arguments`

Then instead of three separate functions for creating three separate columns, one for year, one for month, one for day.

Once the string is a date time object (dt), I believe the code is: `return dt.year, return dt.month, return dt.day`.

I would like one function which adds three columns to my dataframe, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the format string as a positional argument.

```
>>> import time
>>> def convertdate(dstring):
...     return time.strptime(dstring, '%Y-%m-%d')
...
>>> convertdate('2013-03-02')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=61, tm_isdst=-1)
```

BTW, [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) returns [`time.struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time). Its attributes are prefixed with `tm_`.

More preferably you can use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> def convertdate(dstring):
...     return datetime.datetime.strptime(dstring, '%Y-%m-%d')
...
>>> dt = convertdate('2013-03-02')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 2, 0, 0)
>>> pd.DataFrame([{'year': dt.year, 'month': dt.month, 'day': dt.day}])
   day  month  year
0    2      3  2013
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, what is the difference between your two answers, time.strptime, and datetime.datetime.strptime?

Comment: @yoshiserry, They returns different object. `time.strptime` returns `time.struct_time` object, while `datetime.datetime.strptime` returns `datetime` object. They have different attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas now supports `pandas.to_datetime` for converting str to date.
eg to create a new column of dates from a string col:

```
import pandas as pd
df['My Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Str'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

To split into numbers:

```
df['My Year'] = df['My Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
df['My Month'] = df['My Date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
df['My Day'] = df['My Date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
```

To split into string columns, use the `.dt.strftime`, eg for a month name like "Jan"

```
df['Month'] = df['My Date'].dt.strftime('%b')
```

More info:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html